# Parses XML to return the bus times at specified bus stop

Tags: python, beginner, xml, beautifulsoup, curl

The code uses the XML-based [OC Transpo data feed](http://www.octranspo.com/developers/documentation) to create a list of the bus name, where it's headed, and the times. Keep in mind that I am a beginner at python so any advice at all is appreciated.

```
import subprocess, pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def format_set(result_set):
    new_set = []
    for el in result_set:
        new_set.append(str(el.get_text()))
    return new_set



def get_stop_number():
    print('Please enter your desired stop number (or \'quit\'):')
    stop_numb = raw_input('> ')
    try:
        return int(stop_numb)
    except:
        print('Exiting...')
        return 'quit'


def get_stop_info(stopNo):
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(('curl -d "appID=ba91e757&apiKey=…'
            '&stopNo={}&format=xml" https://api.octranspo1.com/v1.2/GetNextTripsForStopAllRoutes').format(stopNo), shell=True)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(output, 'xml')
    except:
        print('An error occured!')
        return None
    summary = []
    for el in soup.find_all('Route'):
        routeNo = int(el.find('RouteNo').get_text()) 
        routeHeading = str(el.find('RouteHeading').get_text())
        times = format_set(el.find_all('TripStartTime'))
        x = [routeNo, routeHeading, times]
        summary.append(x)
    return summary


def is_empty(any_structure):
    if any_structure:
        return False
    else:
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        stop_number = get_stop_number()
        if stop_number == 'quit':
            break
        summary = get_stop_info(stop_number)
        pprint.pprint(summary)
```

Sample output:

> ```
> Please enter your desired stop number (or 'quit'):
> > 3058
>   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
> 100  7756  100  7679  100    77   4654     46  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  4656
> [[92, 'St-Laurent', ['11:30', '12:00', '12:30']],
>  [92, 'Stittsville', []],
>  [96, 'St-Laurent', ['10:51', '11:21', '11:51']],
>  [96, 'Terry Fox', ['10:09', '10:39', '11:09']],
>  [118, 'Hurdman', ['11:20', '11:40', '12:00']],
>  [118, 'Kanata', []],
>  [162, 'Stittsville', ['11:55', '12:55', '13:55']],
>  [162, 'Terry Fox', []],
>  [168, 'Bridlewood', ['11:35', '12:05', '12:35']],
>  [168, 'Terry Fox', []]]
> Please enter your desired stop number (or 'quit'):
> > quit
> Exiting...
> ```

Answer (score 1):

- Imports are okay, you'll find different advice about whether to import
  individual functions, so I'll say no more.
- You have `__name__ ...`, good, perhaps just move the contained block
  into another function `main` so that you can easily invoke it from the
  REPL.
- `is_empty` is obsolete, at some point you'll just remember that empty
  lists are `False` in a boolean context.  Oh and it's unused as well.
- You have a lot of quoting options in Python, so if you need a literal
  `'` in a string, consider delimiting it with `"` instead of using the
  backslash syntax.
- You're in Python, so perhaps also use the built-in HTTP library
  instead of shelling out to `curl`.
- `format_set` is more easily written with a list comprehension, e.g.:

  ```
  def format_set(result_set):
      return [str(el.get_text()) for el in result_set]
  ```
- Technically `get_stop_number` accepts more than just numbers and
  `'quit'`, so just be aware of that.  I'd inline the `stop_numb`
  variable as well (n.b. why care about saving two characters there?)

  ```
  ...
  return int(raw_input('> '))
  ```
- `get_stop_info` has a camel-case variable s, that's inconsistent with
  the rest and in general not advised in Python.  Again, the loop can be
  a list comprehension, but maybe that'll be a bit too dense, your
  choice.  In general returning an unstructured list like is will also
  prevent the reader from getting a clearer understanding of the code,
  but if it's just for display purposes that's fine.

  ```
  ...
  return [[int(el.find('RouteNo').get_text()),
           str(el.find('RouteHeading').get_text()),
           format_set(el.find_all('TripStartTime'))]
          for el in soup.find_all('Route')]
  ```
- I'm a fan of aggressively factoring out common code, you can try and
  see how you like e.g. creating smaller functions for
  `int(el.find(name).get_text())` and so on; that can be helpful later
  on as your program(s) grow(s).